# CAS Authentication with Sub-domain

Tags: cas, rubycas-server, rubycas-client

I have setup CAS server in Java and using RubyCas-client for my application. Now my application runs on sub-domain so my concern is once I am authenticated by CAS server for some particular sub-domain, I am able to access others sub-domain also.

Here is brief example:-

My CAS server URL is `https://localhost:8443/cas/login`

I have given credentials for `sub-domain1.mydomain.com` and got authenticated for same but when I am trying to access `sub-domain2.mydomain.com`, getting authenticated for `sub-domain2` and `sub-domain3` and so on also.

What I want to do that for each sub-domain it will ask me for credentials. Is this possible.

Thanks in advance!